# What tax form do I use to file 2021 federal taxes AFTER extension?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, extension

Filing paper form 4868 for extension. Still making payment by check.

What form do I use to file 2021 federal taxes? I searched instructions and it says put payment I made in Schedule 3, Line 10.

Where do I reflect Schedule 3, Line 10 in 2021 1040 Form?

Or is there another form to file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Schedule 3, line 15, says (my bolding):

> Add lines 9 through 12 and 14. Enter here and **on Form 1040, 1040-SR, or 1040-NR, line 31**

So line 10 itself does not map to a line on Form 1040 or equivalent, but is seen in Schedule 3, line 15, and Form 1040 or equivalent, line 31. Therefore, you need to file the **appropriate Form 1040**.